# Javascript prevent click while processing a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript, please bear with me.

I have a code similar to the one below, whenever I click a button, it performs some animation on a HTML element, problem is, if the user clicks multiple times, the animation will be buffered and executed with a huge delay all at once.

The code below "should" solve the problem by disabling the loop until the animation completes, but it doesn't. I can not change the code's structure too much, it must stay in this form more or less.

```
var processing = false;

$("p").click(function() {
  if (processing == false) {
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      if (processing == false)
        processing = true;
      tastor();
    }
    processing = false;
  }
});


function tastor() {
  zubi = parseFloat($('p').css('font-size'));
  $('p').animate({'font-size': zubi+i}, 500);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/stop/ at all?

Comment: For reference, [this video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/79-complete-jquery-animations/) covers animation queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) jQuery pseudo-selector to break out early in case the element is already animating:

```
$("p").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':animated')) return;

  // The rest of your normal code.
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MgmET/4/**

Answer (score 0):

"animate" may start an event lasting half a second, but it does not actually take half a second to execute. So, each "tastor" call per click will execute quite quickly, before the next click happens.

One way to fix this would be to rely on the "complete" property of animate. You can pass a function to animate that will not execute until the animation has finished. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/FYxt5/1/):

```
var processing = false;
var increment = 1;
function step (count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        tastor(function() { step(count - 1) });
    } else {
        processing = false;
    }
}
$("p").click(function() {
    if (processing == false) {
        processing = true;
        step(5);
    }
});
function tastor(callback) {
    zubi = parseFloat($('p').css('font-size'));
    $('p').animate({'font-size': zubi+increment}, 500, callback);
}
```

​